# Cypher / Should I use the WITH clause to pass values to next MATCH?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Using Neo4j 2.1.X, let's suppose this query, returning the user 123's friends that bought a Car:

```
MATCH (u1:User("123"))-[:KNOWS]-(friend)
MATCH (friend)-[:BUYS]->(c:Car)
RETURN friend
```

In this [article](http://wes.skeweredrook.com/the-mythical-with-neo4js-cypher-query-language/), it is written regarding the `WITH` clause:

> So, how does it work? Well, with is basically just a stream, as lazy
>   as it can be (as lazy as return can be), passing results on to the
>   next query.

So it seems I should transform the query like this:

```
MATCH (u1:User("123"))-[:KNOWS]-(friend)
WITH friend
MATCH (friend)-[:BUYS]->(c:Car)
RETURN friend
```

Should I? Or does the current version of Cypher already handle `MATCH` chaining while passing values through them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The more accurate starting point you give in the upfront of your query, the more efficient it will be.

Your first match is not so accurate, indeed it will use the traversal matcher to match all possible relationships.

Taken the following neo4j console example : http://console.neo4j.org/r/jsx71g

And your first query who will look like this in the example :

```
MATCH (n:User { login: 'nash99' })-[:KNOWS]->(friend)
RETURN count(*)
```

You can see the amount of dbhits in the upfront :

```
    Execution Plan

    ColumnFilter
      |
      +EagerAggregation
        |
        +Filter
          |
          +TraversalMatcher

    +------------------+------+--------+-------------+-----------------------------------------+
    |         Operator | Rows | DbHits | Identifiers |                                   Other |
    +------------------+------+--------+-------------+-----------------------------------------+
    |     ColumnFilter |    1 |      0 |             |                   keep columns count(*) |
    | EagerAggregation |    1 |      0 |             |                                         |
    |           Filter |    8 |    320 |             | Property(n,login(2)) == {  AUTOSTRING0} |
    | TraversalMatcher |  160 |    201 |             |             friend,   UNNAMED32, friend |
    +------------------+------+--------+-------------+-----------------------------------------+
Total database accesses: 521
```

If you use a more accurate starting point, you're the king of the road when you start from this point, look at this example query and see the difference in db hits :

```
Execution Plan

ColumnFilter
  |
  +EagerAggregation
    |
    +SimplePatternMatcher
      |
      +Filter
        |
        +NodeByLabel

+----------------------+------+--------+------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
|             Operator | Rows | DbHits |            Identifiers |                                   Other |
+----------------------+------+--------+------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
|         ColumnFilter |    1 |      0 |                        |                   keep columns count(*) |
|     EagerAggregation |    1 |      0 |                        |                                         |
| SimplePatternMatcher |    8 |      0 | n, friend,   UNNAMED51 |                                         |
|               Filter |    1 |     40 |                        | Property(n,login(2)) == {  AUTOSTRING0} |
|          NodeByLabel |   20 |     21 |                   n, n |                                   :User |
+----------------------+------+--------+------------------------+-----------------------------------------+

Total database accesses: 61
```

So to terminate your query, I will do something like this :

```
MATCH (n:User { login: 'nash99' })
WITH n
MATCH (n)-[:KNOWS]->(friend)-[:BUYS]->(c:Car)
RETURN friend
```

You can also specify that the friends can not be the same as the user :

```
MATCH (n:User { login: 'nash99' })
    WITH n
    MATCH (n)-[:KNOWS]->(friend)-[:BUYS]->(c:Car)
    WHERE NOT friend.id = n.id
    RETURN friend
```

Note that there is no difference between the above query and the following in matter of db hits :

```
MATCH (n:User { login: 'nash99' })
WITH n
MATCH (n)-[:KNOWS]->(friend)
WITH friend
MATCH (friend)-[:BUYS)->(c:Car)
RETURN (friend)
```

I recommend that you use the neo4j console to look at the result details showing you the above informations.

If you need to quickly protoype a graph for test, you can use Graphgen, export the graph in cypher statements and load these statements in the neo4j console.

Here is the link to the graphgen generation I used for the console http://graphgen.neoxygen.io/?graph=29l9XJ0HxJ2pyQ

Chris

Comment: I made a mistake in my query. It should have been:  `MATCH (u1:User {id: "123"})-[:KNOWS]-(friend)`. You wrote: "Your first match is not so accurate". Why? Since I'm using a label with `id` property indexed....

Comment: Yes you are using labels, but you're not matching a labelized node but a complete pattern instead. look at the result details, it is using the traversal matcher so it will traverse the graph to match your pattern, with my proposal it is using the labels index instead

Comment: Oh... I thought that the behavior would be: "The first node is labelized, so I (cypher engine) firstly match it, and THEN, I'll traverse the specified path". If I well understand, you are saying that the behavior is in my case: "Let's traverse the path and I will only retain the nodes matching the index"...obvisouly leading to a full traversal matching. Do I well figure it out?

Comment: Cypher focuses on the clarity of WHAT to retrieve from a graph, not HOW to retrieve it. So in your case it will use the traversal matcher and the label index will not be used by the way

Comment: So to sum up, I could assert: Never use a labelized node directly in some pattern.

Comment: No you can and you should, the problem is that you do not define a specific starting point. If you translate you're saying to Cypher "hey find me all possible relationships with type KNOWS that are connected to the user 123", you should better saying "Hey Cypher, find me user 123 using the label index, then from this user find all relationships KNWOS connected to me.

Comment: I understand it can be confusing by seeing the pattern you write, but working with small accurate parts in a pattern will give you more performance

Comment: Understood, last question: is there a good documentation about all the "under the hood"? Where did you learn all those things? ;)

Comment: No I don't think there is such documentation, maybe some cookbooks on the neo4j site could be helpful. I recommend you to use the neo4j console and the result details, this is really helpful to understand how your query is handled by Cypher. Check stackoverflow questions and answers and also blog posts from top guys like Michael Hunger, Kenny Bastani, Nicole White, FrobberOfBits, JohnMark18, Mark Needham, GraphAware, Nigel Small, and I sure pass some people. Check also the Neo4j Google Group. And don't hesitate to ask, you're helping you and people looking for the same answers.

Comment: Check well in the console to see to where it is needed to split, and enjoy Neo4j !

Comment: In my case, I don't have a `NodeByLabel`, the console displays a `SchemaIndex` instead. I'm using Neo4j 2.1.2 for now.

Comment: Sorry but very last question... in the Wes's article: http://wes.skeweredrook.com/pragmatic-cypher-optimization-2-0-m06/, he uses this kind of query: `MATCH (u:User)-[:played]->(g) WHERE u.id = {uid}`. Using a `where` clause, is it different from the labelized node? Shouldn't he find the starting point first with: `MATCH (u:User) where u.id = {uid}`, as you suggest?

Comment: can you give a link to the console ? The article is date from 2.0M6 version, I don't remember if what i told you was already the case in that version, there have been a lot of improvements in 2.1.* .

Comment: I'm using the console of my grapheneDB database instance... not sharable unfortunately :(

Comment: maybe you can use the grapghen web app to describe your actual schema and share the link ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63319/discussion-between-mik378-and-christophe-willemsen).